# Sql Server stored procedure that sends emails stored in table

Tags: database, email, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I currently have a stored procedure that is sending out emails, but it's getting an error.  Also, is there some error checking that I can put in place to ensure the email is sent?  I insert data into a table called `outbound_email_queue` the table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.outbound_email_queue(

email_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
out_type varchar(3) NOT NULL,
send_time datetime NULL,
from_addr varchar(100) NOT NULL,
to_addr varchar(254) NOT NULL,
reply_addr varchar(60) NULL,
subject varchar(254) NOT NULL,
letter_body varchar(8000) NOT NULL
```

The stored procedure I'm using is below.
It gets an error on the Commit statement.

It seems to do the delete, even though I leave out the commit. Even if I get it to execute the procedure, it empties the table but it doesn't seem to send the emails.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspEmail]
as
BEGIN

Declare @email_id as bigint
Declare @email_type as nvarchar(3) 
Declare @from_add as nvarchar(100)
Declare @to_add as nvarchar(254) 
Declare @reply_add as nvarchar(60)
Declare @email_prof as nvarchar(80)   
Declare @MySubject as nvarchar(254) 
Declare @Message as nvarchar(MAX) 

Declare EmailCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    Select email_id, out_type, from_addr, to_addr, reply_addr, subject,   
     letter_body from outbound_email_queue 

set @email_prof = (select email_profile from system_file)

OPEN EmailCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM EmailCursor INTO @email_id, @email_type, @from_add, @to_add,    
@reply_add, @MySubject, @Message

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN    -- send the email     


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail       
@profile_name = @email_prof,     
@recipients = @to_add, 
@reply_to = @reply_add, 
@body_format = 'HTML', 
@from_address = @from_add,    
@subject = @MySubject,       
@body = @Message    

DELETE FROM OUTBOUND_EMAIL_QUEUE WHERE EMAIL_ID = @email_id

FETCH NEXT FROM EmailCursor INTO @email_id, @email_type, @from_add, @to_add,     
@reply_add, @MySubject, @Message
END CLOSE EmailCursor 
DEALLOCATE EmailCursor

COMMIT

END

GO
```

Comment: What exactly is your intent regarding the COMMIT at the end?

Comment: After reading from the outbound_email_queue table, and sending out the the email using sp_send_dbmail...  I want to delete that record.  I don't want to send it again.   I would think that I would need a commit, after doing the deletes from the outbound_email_queue.